# 1c-битрикс. не работают категории

Tags: битрикс

здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки (ни капли сарказма)! нужна помощь в след. вопросе: не работают категории(навигация) на сайте на цмс 1с-битрикс, менял в иноблоках менял в настройках, не помогло не знаю что еще думать, подскажите... при этом выгрузка категории и товаров должна происходить из базы 1с, может это не корректные настройки со стороны 1с или дело в базе mysql??? подскажите кто чем может... вот сайт на котором не работает http://privet-shop.md/ спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

закрываю свой вопрос. если кто еще столкнется то ... 
"Проверьте .htaccess в корне сайта - при переносе скрипт восстановления его переименовывает в .htaccess_xxxxx (xxxx не помню как пишется). Целесообразность такого переименования до сих пор для меня загадка, но вот так битриксы стали делать"